# Implement a GPS example in android

Tags: android, gps

I am an Android beginer. I am trying to implement a GPS example. When I tried, I get `Error : couldn't get connection factory client.`

My API-key is correct, how can I resolve this error?

Comment: show the code that's throwing this error/exception. Also, the question is vague.

Comment: try to search your problem in google or SO first

Answer (score 1):

Try to run it on the real time device.

(OR)

When You are running on the emulator Definitely U will get the Error,

To solve the issue..
Got0->windows-showview->emulatorcontrol->Send latitude and longitude By default to the emulator....

Then u will get the output..